# WPF change UserControl textblock from another window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

Hey all I am new at WPF so here is my question:

How can I change the text in a TextBlock from my mainWindow when the textBlock is in the window named curTemp.xaml?

curTemp.xaml code:

```
public partial class curTemp : UserControl
    {
        public string _valTempChange
        {
            get { return middleForcastCurrentTemp.Text; }
            set { middleForcastCurrentTemp.Text = value; }
        }

        public curTemp()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Xaml of the above UserControl:

```
<Grid>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="5" Foreground="White" Panel.ZIndex="7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="15,-110,-43,0" Width="198" Height="122">
            <TextBlock.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="4" Direction="0" ShadowDepth="0" />
            </TextBlock.Effect>
                    <outlineText:OutlinedTextBlock Height="146" Width="192" TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Aliased" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="100" x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="middleForcastCurrentTemp" 
                                            FontWeight="Medium" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Right" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" Fill="White" Text="10"/>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
```

And in my MainWindow code:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            curTemp _curTempWindow = new curTemp();

            _curTempWindow._valTempChange = "55";

        }
```

When I run that code it never shows "55" in the textBlock. It only shows my default text "10".

What am I doing incorrect here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the current object of the user control.
Currently you are creating a new object.
I am not sure how you are using the user control and what pattern you use.

> You can create a singleton instance in user control and access the
>   user control instance from Main Window.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of `curTemp` in the constructor of your `MainWindow` but you don't display it.

May it be that you create a `curTemp` instance in the XAML code of your `MainWindow`? Then you don't modify the text of this displayed `curTemp` instance but the text of the newly created (second) but not shown `curTemp` instance called `_curTempWindow`

Answer (score 0):

`curTemp` is not a window. It's a `UserControl`. Where do you create the instance of this `UserControl` that you actually see on the screen? Probably in your XAML markup, i.e. in `MainWindow.xaml`.

You could then give the element an `x:Name` in XAML:

```
<local:curTemp x:Name="uc" />
```

...and set the `_valTempChange` property of this instance using its name:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    uc._curTempWindow._valTempChange = "55";
}
```